# Parsing raw bytes into a date in Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a log of a data stream and I'm trying to parse it into something usable.

The documentation I have says that it should start with a block header and that bytes 4,5,6,7 are a Unix date time.

It says convert these 4 bytes to an Int32 to get the total seconds.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "tsl")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath!)

do {

    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

    let timestamp_bytes = Array(data[4..<8])

    let timestamp_data = Data(bytes: timestamp_bytes)

    let timestamp_value = UInt32(bigEndian: timestamp_data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee })

    let timestamp_date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(timestamp_value))

} catch { }
```

This doesn't produce a timestamp at the point I'm expecting, it's in 2026 sometime.

Am I even approaching this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually the fourth byte has index 3, indexes are zero based.

Comment: May be a good idea to print out the individual bytes, do the math yourself and see what the expected value is.

Comment: one moment - i'm going to check if that was a typo or the solution!

Comment: OK so it looks like I explained it slightly ambiguously. There are 4 bytes before the timestamp and then it should be the next 4 so I think the code is using the right bytes

Comment: Joshua - I get these as the actual bytes using Array(data[4..<8])
89, 64, 189, 169
How would I do the math myself?

Comment: Please share the documentation and the raw data you're using.

Comment: Unfortunately they're confidential so I can't :( but ask ask me anything...

Comment: Depending upon little or big endian, I'm getting values of either 29 March 2060 or 14 June 2017. Are you sure about those values? Are you sure it's in 2026?

Comment: Yes this is the problem. should be march this year. Is there any other way to interpret those bytes into a date than a unix timestamp? it says they are a Unix date time

Comment: If you want help decoding bytes, we need to know the exact sequence of bytes and the exact date that represents. To say "2026 sometime" or even "should be march this year" is not precise enough. Give us the precise date (inc timezone) and the sequence of 4 bytes. Having said this, it seems like a remarkable coincidence that `89, 64, 189, 169` gave me 14 June 2017, roughly three months away from the March date you said it should be.

Comment: @JonathanPlackett to do the math yourself, you need to convert each of those bytes into its hexadecimal representation(59, 40, BD, A9), concatenate them to form one 32 bit number (0x5940BDA9), convert back to decimal (1,497,415,081), then convert that number with an epoch converter such as `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)` or epochconverter.com (GMT: Wednesday, June 14, 2017 4:38:01 AM)